# juju handshake node error..why (juju.state open.g:93 TLS handshake failed: x509:certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Tags: juju, maas

there is an error on the node..reads

```
2014-05-25 14:00:00 ERROR juju.state open.g:93 TLS handshake failed: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
2014-05-25 14:00:01 ERROR juju.state open.g:93 TLS handshake failed: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid...
2014-05-25 14:00:02 ERROR juju.state open.g:93 TLS handshake failed: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid...
```

this happends during bootstrap and, i believe this is why MaaS does not report to juju that the bootstrap node is ready?

this repeats it self every second until environments is destroy..

how do you correct this. let me add this is real metal not vm

Comment: this is a confirmed bug, under https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1245550. although it has been triaged, this will put my proof of concept for ubuntu 12.04.4 on hold indefinitely, or until this is corrected. 2nd ubuntu 14.04, also has an impi issue that also halts this proof of concept. both projects are now on hold..

Answer (score 1):

this is a confirmed bug, under bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1245550. and
https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1324331 although it has been triaged, this will put my proof of concept for ubuntu 12.04.4 on hold indefinitely, or until this is corrected. ubuntu 14.04, also has an impi issue that also halts this proof of concept. both projects are now on hold..